# access to url parameter in FormRequest laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

To update a user I used a FormRequest named `UserByAdminFormRequest` like this :

```
public function rules()
    {
        switch ($this->method()) {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE': {
                //some Rules
            }
            case 'POST': {
                //some Rules
            }
            case 'PUT':
                $user_id = $this->get('user_id');

                dd($this);

                return [
                    'name'        => 'required',
                    'email'       => 'email|unique:users,email,' . $user_id . ',user_id',
                    'password'    => 'min:4',
                    're-password' => 'required_unless:password,' . NULL . '|same:password',
                ];


            case 'PATCH': {
                //some Rules
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
```

As you can see `email` field should be unique but to ignore current user in this case, I need to her `user_id` value.

For that I used `$this->get('user_id')` but it return `null` value always.

I used that FormRequest like this in my controller :

```
public function update(UserByAdminFormRequest $request, \App\User $user)
    {
        //
    }
```

And the url that I called by PUT method is (for example) :

```
http://api.zarsystem.dev/v1/dashboard/user/7
```

What can I do in this case Or is there any alternate ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

> $this->get('user_id')

you need to use

> $this->user_id

to get the value of user id, make sure you have input field or hidden filed with name user_id.

Comment: I found that I should be used `$this->user->user_id` and problem is solved now.